# UIPickerView with JSON object

Tags: ios, iphone, json, xcode, uipickerview

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://advantixcrm.com/prj/mitech/index.php/api/appconfig/Mx"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

NSArray *array=[jsonArray objectForKey:@"RestInfo"];

for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    NSString*location=[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"restaurant_location"];
    [data addObject:location];
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component{
switch (component) {
    case 0:
        return [data count];
        break;

    default:
        return 0;
        break;
}
return 0;
}

 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
switch (component) {
    case 0:
        return [data objectAtIndex:row];
        break;

    default:
        return 0;
        break;
}
}
```

I want to bring my JSON object to UIPickerView, but I was only get "?".

How can I bring my data into UIPickerView?

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Question is not clear. What problem you are facing now?

Comment: What are you getting into the data array?

Comment: i want to get the object "restaurant_location" from json to display in uipickerview

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not reloading your `UIPickerView`, So Just Reload your picker view after getting data.

```
data=[NSMutableArray new];
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    NSString*location=[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"restaurant_location"];
    [data addObject:location];
}
[yourPickerView reloadComponent:0];


//If you want to reload complete pickerView then
[yourPickerView reloadAllComponents];
```